# Get total seconds in of period of time over day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this problem: I need to calculate the time in seconds of a labor time, excepting the time of interval, for different turns.

So, I have this table:

```
cdLaborTime nmLaborTime beginLaborTime endLaborTime beginInterval endInterval
----------- ----------- -------------  ------------ ------------- --------------
1           1st Turn    07:30          16:45        11:00         12:00
2           2nd Turn    16:45          01:30        20:00         21:00
```

The main problem: Sometimes we have turns that start in one day and finish in the next day.

I have created this view to help me:

```
CREATE VIEW v_LaborTime
AS

SELECT CASE 
        WHEN CAST(beginLaborTime AS TIME) < CAST(endLaborTime AS TIME)
            THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, beginLaborTime, endLaborTime) - DATEDIFF(SECOND, beginInterval, endInterval)
        ELSE (DATEDIFF(SECOND, beginLaborTime, '23:59') + DATEDIFF(SECOND, '00:00', endLaborTime)) - DATEDIFF(SECOND, beginInterval, endInterval)
        END AS TotalSeconds

        , CASE 
        WHEN CAST(beginLaborTime AS TIME) < CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) AND CAST(beginInterval AS TIME) < CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) AND CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) > endInterval
            THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, beginLaborTime, CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME)) - DATEDIFF(SECOND, beginInterval, endInterval)
        WHEN CAST(beginLaborTime AS TIME) < CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) AND CAST(beginInterval AS TIME) < CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME)
            THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, beginLaborTime, CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME)) - DATEDIFF(SECOND, beginInterval, CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME))
        WHEN CAST(beginLaborTime AS TIME) < CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) AND CAST(beginInterval AS TIME) > CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME)
            THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, beginLaborTime, CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME))
        WHEN CAST(beginLaborTime AS TIME) > CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) AND CAST(beginInterval AS TIME) < CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) AND CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) > endInterval
            THEN (DATEDIFF(SECOND, beginLaborTime, '23:59') + DATEDIFF(SECOND, '00:00', CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME))) - DATEDIFF(SECOND, beginInterval, endInterval)
        WHEN CAST(beginLaborTime AS TIME) > CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) AND CAST(beginInterval AS TIME) < CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME)
            THEN (DATEDIFF(SECOND, beginLaborTime, '23:59') + DATEDIFF(SECOND, '00:00', CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME))) - DATEDIFF(SECOND, beginInterval, CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME))
        ELSE (DATEDIFF(SECOND, beginLaborTime, '23:59') + DATEDIFF(SECOND, '00:00', CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME)))
        END AS CurrentSeconds

        ,CASE 
        WHEN CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) >= beginLaborTime AND (CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) < endLaborTime OR (beginLaborTime > endLaborTime))
            THEN 'OPEN'
        ELSE
            'CLOSE'
        END AS 'cdState'
        , cdLaborTime
        , nmLaborTime
        , beginLaborTime
        , endLaborTime
        , beginInterval
        , endInterval
FROM [laborTime]
```

It is working, but it is too big and strange, is there any better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Question 1: the 4 'time' columns are varchars?

Comment: Question 2: These columns may be null?

Comment: Question 3: The labor time may exceed 24h?

Comment: Question 4: Why are you checking the begin- and end-times with the current time?

Comment: Why are the LaborTimes and Interval times not using DATETIME datatypes?

Comment: Question 5: Is it possible for the interval to start in one day and finish the next day (for instance, from 23:30 to 00:30)?

Comment: All of the fields are varchar, this is the model of the customer uses, I cannot change it. The columns are not null. The labor time cannot exceed 24 hours.

Comment: 4. I need to get two things, spent time of the open turn and total time.

Comment: 5. Yes it is, i'm not covering right now I'm my view, thanks for that!

Comment: Besides all these questions and suggested answers above, I'd also put these calculations to a function and call that function to get my values.